# Cron job not putting Redis in slave mode

Tags: cron, ubuntu-12.04, redis

My organization has Redis running in a Master/Slave configuration, using Keepalived to switch between the two. It was discovered that when the Slave instance dies for some reason, Keepalived will not restart it. I started writing a cron job to check and see if redis is running, and if the slave dies, to restart it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#redis_cron_restart.sh
######variables########
REDIS_IP="10.19.105.229"
REDIS_CONF="/var/lib/redis/redis.conf"
#Check to see if Redis is running
killall -0 redis-server
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
        then
                date >> /var/lib/redis/log.txt
                echo redis-server not running. Checking redis master >> /var/lib/redis/log.txt
                redis-cli -h ${REDIS_IP} PING
                if [ $? -eq 1 ]
                        then
                                echo redis master not running. Doing nothing. >> /var/lib/redis/log.txt
                        else
                                echo redis master is running. I must be the slave. Restarting keepalived >> /var/lib/redis/log.txt
                                redis-server ${REDIS_CONF}
                                sleep 1
                                wait
                                redis-cli SLAVEOF ${REDIS_IP} 6379
                fi
        else
                echo redis-server running. >> /var/lib/redis/log.txt
fi
```

It runs, and it restarts Redis. It does not, however, put Redis into slave mode. If I type

```
redis-cli SLAVEOF 10.19.105.229 6379
```

at my terminal, however, it goes into slave mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it possible that, in your innermost `else` block, the call to `redis-server` is returning immediately, but the server itself is taking more than one second to start up? In that case, `wait` won't wait long enough.

Comment: Bingo. I moved the Wait below the Sleep, and I changed it to Sleep 5.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried writing the complete path to redis-cli and redis-server in the script? Or simply set the PATH variable at the beginning of the script and make it the same that you see when you type `echo $PATH` in your terminal.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.